# Usando ActionName en Web API

Tags: ajax, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Estoy trabajando con visual basic y AJAX, quiero acceder a la siguiente dirección en mi controlador que se llama Catalogos:

```
    <HttpGet>
    <ActionName("BuscarProgramacion")>
    Public Function BuscarProgramacion(ByVal IdCuestionario As Integer) As List(Of ListaCatalogo)
        Dim Lista = sCatalogosEncuesta.ObtenerCatalogo(IdCuestionario)
        Return Lista
    End Function
```

ya configuré el WebApiConfig de la siguiente manera:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name:="DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name:="ActionApi",
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{IdCuestionario}",
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
   )
```

y mi función AJAX es la siguiente:

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:7910/api/Catalogos/BuscarProgramacion/5';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + OnLoadRA.token },
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            404: function (error) {
                jAlertError('Error al cargar la información.', 'Mensaje del servidor')
            }
        }
    });
```

pero no logro acceder al controlador, me marca el siguiente error:

{"Message":"No se ha encontrado ningún recurso HTTP que coincida con la URI de la solicitud 'http://localhost:7910/api/Catalogos/BuscarProgramacion/5?_=1492022653760'.","MessageDetail":"No se encontró ninguna acción en el controlador 'Catalogos' que coincida con el nombre 'BuscarProgramacion'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que ese action se encuentra dentro de un `ApiController` de nombre `CatalogosController`

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

[Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Recomendaria evalues usar el atributo de routing `[Route]` es mas practico para definir como resuelve la url del action

[Create a REST API with Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

Ademas no veo que definas un `success` en el `$.ajax` para trabajar los datos que devuelva

Si defines la url por medio de [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) podrias probar la invocacion del webapi sin necesidad de ejecutar el codigo

Comment: Gracias Leandro Tuttini, probé con cambiarle a un ruteo, me basé en uno de los enlaces que publicaste y logré hacer el ruteo:

<HttpGet>
<Route("api/ResumenAciertos/{IdResumenAcierto}/ResumenAciertos")>

Y no habia pasado desde ese día por aquí, por eso no había comentado, muchas gracias por el apoyo